# Add rel to all images in a post

Tags: theme-development, images, filters

I want to add a `rel` to all images in a post. I am trying following filter but it will wrap only the images which are in the gallery. It does not wrap the images which are added individually without the gallery.

How can I add the `rel` to all images in the gallery or without the gallery?

```
function add_rel($link) {
    return str_replace('<a href', '<a rel="lightbox" href', $link);
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'add_rel');
```

Answer (score -2):

something like this can be useful:

```
function image_tag($html, $id, $alt, $title) {
    return preg_replace(array(
            '/'.str_replace('//','//',get_bloginfo('url')).'/i',
            '/s+width="d+"/i',
            '/s+height="d+"/i',
            '/alt=""/i'
        ),
        array(
            '',
            '',
            '',
            'alt="' . $title . '"'
        ),
        $html);
}
add_filter('get_image_tag', 'image_tag', 0, 4);
```

Comment: Please explain *why* it can be useful. Please do not dump code as an answer. You should **always** explain how your code work and what it does

Comment: `str_replace('//','//',get_bloginfo('url'))` – really?

Comment: I just gave an example to filter each image tag, and change attributes. You should give an answer to @jay and don't opine in my answer,.